# Symfony 2's NelmioSolariumBundle and issues with Monolog

Tags: symfony, solr, composer-php, monolog

I'm trying install [NelmioSolariumBundle](https://github.com/nelmio/NelmioSolariumBundle) with my Symfony 2 application by following the [read me](https://github.com/nelmio/NelmioSolariumBundle/blob/master/README.md), however after registering the bundle within the `AppKernal.php` I receive` the following error:

`ErrorException: Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Nelmio\SolariumBundle\Logger::setLogger() must be an instance of Psr\Log\LoggerInterface, instance of Symfony\Bridge\Monolog\Logger given, called in /var/www/vhosts/symfony.example.com/app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php on line 2096 and defined in /var/www/vhosts/symfony.example.com/vendor/nelmio/solarium-bundle/Nelmio/SolariumBundle/Logger.php line 44`

After a bit of digging I found [this article](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/psr-huh/) that states:

> Monolog recently implemented PSR-3. It’s therefore known to implement the Psr\Log\LoggerInterface and its associated guidelines found in the PSR-3 document.

So now I'm trying to update my version of MonoLog and receive the following error within composer and am unsure where to go from here:

Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

```
Problem 1
- Installation request for symfony/monolog-bundle 2.2.* -> satisfiable by symfony/monolog-bundle v2.2.0.
- Conclusion: remove symfony/symfony v2.1.9
- symfony/monolog-bundle v2.2.0 requires symfony/monolog-bridge >=2.2-beta2,<3.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/symfony v2.2.0, symfony/symfony v2.2.1, symfony/monolog-bridge v2.2.0, symfony/monolog-bridge v2.2.1.
- Can only install one of: symfony/symfony v2.2.0, symfony/symfony v2.1.9.
- Can only install one of: symfony/symfony v2.2.1, symfony/symfony v2.1.9.
- don't install symfony/monolog-bridge v2.2.0|don't install symfony/symfony v2.1.9
- don't install symfony/monolog-bridge v2.2.1|don't install symfony/symfony v2.1.9
- Installation request for symfony/symfony == 2.1.9.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/symfony v2.1.9.
```

Do I need to completely update my Symfony 2 version in order to get it working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately due to the new interface etc it was not possible to keep things working with both cases. So Symfony 2.2+ and MonologBundle 2.2+ are required to use Monolog 1.4+.

That said, it seems to be a bug in the bundle that it requires the PSR LoggerInterface, because the old interface of Symfony is also compatible. I just pushed a v2.0.1 of the bundle, if you'd like to update and see if that works (you can rollback the changes to the requirements of monolog).

Comment: I see. I rolled back to the 1.x branch and everything is working as it should. Moving forward though I'm going to upgrade to 2.2+ as the project I'm working on is still in the early stages of development. Great bundle by the way!